# How to access the java variables in the mule flows

Tags: java, mule

Scenario:
I have a variable in the Java file, which I want to access in the mule config xml. How do I do that.

Example - There is a web service which passes params like this

```
localhost/apiname?name="dynamic data"
```

So while hitting the web service I want to pass param "name" as a dynamic data. How do I do that. I assume if I'm able to access the Java variable in the xml file then that will be possible.

Comment: This question is very unclear... As a general answer, yes you can get in your flow whatever is passed in any HTTP request sent to Mule.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer

I did it like this
1. Created a property file
2. In that I created a variable com.webparam.url = "http://localhost?name="
3. In the mule config accessed the property file
4. And accessed the variable like this
`<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="HttpsConnector" transformer-address="${com.webparam.paramName}test>`

With this the mule evaluated it to `localhost?name=test`.

Tried to seperate out the url part with the param "name" and then concatenate the 2 strings but it seems that mule was not doing that. I used mule 3.2.

Answer (score -1):

I usually store variables in SESSION then I can access it whenever I want like this

```
localhost/apiname?name=[header:session:name]
```